# Why is the sum of two independent geometrically distributed RVs not geometrically distributed again?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let X = Geo(1/4) and Y = Geo(1/4) (both independent) and let Z = X + Y.

Why is X + Y not Geo(0.5) for example and how could I, as an example, calculate P(Z = 3)?

Comment: Why do you think it has to be geometric?

Comment: Hint: [Negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)

Comment: The count of independent Bernoulli trials with identical success rate *until* the first success, has a Geometric Distribution. $~$ The sum of two such random variables, with identical success rate parameter, would be a count of independent Bernoulli trials until the *second* success. $~$ That is not a Geometrically distributed random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is $X+Y$ not $\operatorname{Geo}(0.5)$ ?

Notice that 
$$P(X+Y=z \mid X = k) = P(X = k \cap Y = z-k)=P(X=k)P(Y=z-k) \tag{1}$$
Using the probability of a geometric distribution, that is
$$P(X=k) = p(1-p)^{k-1}\tag{2}$$
Also
$$P(Y=z-k) = p(1-p)^{z-k-1}\tag{3}$$
Replace $(2),(3)$ in $(1)$, you get:
$$P(X+Y=z) =p(1-p)^{k-1}p(1-p)^{z-k-1}=p^2(1-p)^{k-1+z-k-1} $$
which is 
$$P(X+Y=z \mid X = k) = p^2(1-p)^{z-2}$$
Now marginalize over $k$ as 
$$P(X+Y=z) = \sum_k P(X+Y=z \mid X = k)  = \sum_{k=1}^{z-1} p^2(1-p)^{z-2}$$

Notice that:
\begin{align} P(X+Y = z) &=\sum_{k=1}^{z-1} p^2(1-p)^{z-2} \\
& = p^2(1-p)^{z-2}\sum_{k=1}^{z-1} 1 \\
& =  p^2(1-p)^{z-2}(z-1) \\
& \neq (2p)(1-2p)^z
\end{align}
where $p = 0.25$ in your case.

Comment: How did you exactly get this: P(X+Y=z)= $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} p^2(1-p)^{z-2}$$

Comment: @LION edited please check

Comment: Aha ok I see thanks for the effort that you have put in your answer. The only things lef that I don't understnad is where the upper-bound z-1 come from. Why isn't it z for example?

Comment: because geometric distribution support starts at 1 not 0. So if we reach $z$, it means that $Y$ will take the value $0$, which does not happen.

Comment: Ah ok I got it thanks for the thorough explanation.

Comment: my pleasure @LION

Comment: Alternatively: We see the probabilitiy for obtaining an arrangement of exactly $1$ success *among* the first $z-1$ trials, followed by a second success in trial $z$.  $$\binom{z-1}1~(1-p)^{z-2}~p^2~\mathbf 1_{z\in\{2,..\}}$$

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get at the distribution of $Z$ is to condition on the value of one of $X$ or $Y$, first. Let's say we condition on $X=x$. We adopt the convention that $x\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. Now,

\begin{align}
P(Z=z) &= \sum_{x=0}^{z}P(Z=z|X=x)P(X=x)\\
&= \sum_{x=0}^{z}P(Y=z-x)P(X=x) \quad \text{[Independence of X and Y]}\\
&= \sum_{x=0}^{z}(0.75)^{z-x}(0.25)(0.75)^{x}(0.25)\\
&= (z+1)(0.75)^{z}(0.25)^{2}
\end{align}

It is now a simple task to substitute $z=3$ in the expression above, to evaluate $P(Z=3)$. You can note that the resultant distribution above, is called the negative binomial distribution.

Comment: Do you mean: (z - 1)(0.75)(0.25)^(2) ?

Comment: I may be missing something but it looks like that should be $0.75^z$ in the final formula. Also, this is interpreting the geometric distribution as the number of failures before the first success, which is fine, but sometimes it's defined as the number of trials up to and including including the first success which can be confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, that was a typo---it must be $(0.75)^z$.